# Fogbugz case - Assigning case to a user while created using Scoutsubmit.asp page

Tags: fogbugz, fogbugz-api

We are creating fogbugz cases through programming using https://example.com/ScoutSubmit.asp. Can anybody let us know that how to pass value so that the case can be assigned to a particular user on Fogbugz.
Your help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a project and area that has the person you want the case to be assigned to.  Then just make sure scoutsubmit sets the submission to that project and area and the case will automatically be assigned to them.

You'll have more control using the [FogBugz API](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/docs/70/topics/advanced/api.html) but the above will work as well.